# How to install Scriptcs to Sublime

Tags: command-line, visual-studio, sublime-text-3

**How can I install Scriptcs to Sublime ?**
My aim is to use a Visual Studio alternative to run ASP.Net pages on Sublime. 
 To able to do this, I have to add Scriptcs to Sublime. But I couldn’t add it.

What I have done so far :

Trying the steps on
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-run-c-sharp-code-inside-sublime-text/

I have run this in cmd in administrator mode :
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object
System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"

**But couldn't understand this :**

```
To install Sublime Text Package Manager, head over to packagecontrol.io and follow the installation procedure.
```

**and couldn't run the package on**
https://packagecontrol.io

How can I continue and add Scriptcs to Sublime?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to install packages, you need to install Package Control. As far as I know, there should be a menu entry if you're using Sublime Text 3. Otherwise, follow these [instructions for manual installation](https://packagecontrol.io/installation). Once Package Control is installed, you can access install packages by running *"Package Control: Install Package"* from the [command palette](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/command_palette.html). This will open a search box that lets you search and install Scriptcs.

Comment: Thanks I have added Scriptcs but get a build error. I asked it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885737/error-on-running-scriptcs-with-sublime-text-3